# quickfix - Configuration failed: <message> contains no fields

Tags: quickfix

I'm using [quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) with python bindings. Upon initialization while using [`FIX44.xml`](http://www.quickfixengine.org/documentation) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\my_proj\quickfix_app.py", line 1227, in start_app
    initiator = fix.SocketInitiator(self, storeFactory, settings, logFactory )
  File "C:\Users\Me\virtual_environments\my_env\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 34432, in __init__
    SocketInitiatorBase.__init__(self, application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
  File "C:\Users\Me\virtual_environments\my_env\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 34316, in __init__
    this = _quickfix.new_SocketInitiatorBase(*args)
ConfigError: Configuration failed: FIX44.xml: Configuration failed: <message> contains no fields
```

The error originates from the last line in the following code:

```
settings     = fix.SessionSettings('FIX44.xml')
storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory( settings )
logFactory   = fix.ScreenLogFactory(settings)
initiator    = fix.SocketInitiator(self, storeFactory, settings, logFactory )
```

I get the same error for using `FIX43.xml`, however `FIX42.xml` works fine. These xml files check out using an XML validator. As I'm using example xml files from the quickfix site I doubt the problem is with the files.

**What could cause this error?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Incredibly, quickfix isn't compatible with the xml from the quickfix site. I found the following line in `FIX44.xml`:

```
<message name='XMLnonFIX' msgcat='admin' msgtype='n' />
```

Which indeed has no fields. As I don't need this message, I simply removed the line and it works.